# How to invoke shell function in string? (bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I want to invoke shell function in string.  Here is my use case:

```
function envfoo() {
    env ENV_FOO=foo $@
}
function envbar() {
    env ENV_BAR=bar $@
}

$ envfoo env |egrep ENV_
ENV_FOO=foo
$ envbar env |egrep ENV_
ENV_BAR=bar
$ envfoo envbar env |egrep ENV_
env: envbar: No such file or directory
# expected result: ENV_FOO=foo and ENV_BAR=bar lines
```

Here I want `envfoo` to execute `envbar` shell function.
How can I do it?

Say that is opposite of `command` which ignores shell function and finds real command.

---

Maybe I gave a wrong example.  I want to combine multiple shell functions like actual executables.
A real case goes like this:

```
function be() {
    bundle exec $@
}

function envstg() {
    env RAILS_ENV=staging $@
}

$ be rails server
# launches Rails server

$ envstg be rails server
env: be: No such file or directory
```

Here `be` isn't expanded into bundle exec.  How can I expand them?

Comment: Why don't use `(envbar && envfoo) | grep ENV_` ?

Comment: Maybe I gave a wrong example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have the `env` command there, but it works fine if you remove it:

```
$ function be() {
>     echo "$@"
> }

$ function envstg() {
>     RAILS_ENV=staging "$@"
> }
$ be rails server
rails server
$ envstg be rails server
rails server
```